# CMU Sphinx 4 - 5 pre alpha install guide

Tags: java, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

Are there any good, preferably step by step install guides for CMU Sphinx 4 -5prealpha(latest version)? I couldn't find any and the official guide is outdated. I've been trying to follow the steps but after i'm done i'm missing 2 jars(jsapi and tags) and if i try to get them from the version before eclipse doesn't find any of the classes. I haven't had too much experience with seting up such projects for eclipse, all i did before was maybe create some custom libraries so that's why i'm asking for a step by step buide. Any directions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any good, preferably step by step install guides for CMU Sphinx 4 -5prealpha(latest version)?

There is no "install" in Java projects. If you want to compile latest sphinx4 you can do the following steps:

1. Make sure your Eclipse has Maven support
2. Go to http://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4
3. Download zip or checkout repo from git
4. Import with `Import -> Maven -> Existing Project` existing maven project
5. Build and run the demo.

> but after i'm done i'm missing 2 jars(jsapi and tags)

Those were removed, you should not reference them